# Create new Env Variable using existing Env Variables in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, build, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to generate some env. variable in jenkins pipeline project and want to inject them into my build, but so far i am not able to do so, in the below mentioned snippet, i have one env variable already created i.e. ***build=20160107***
random build number, now i execute a batchscript name CalculateTempEnvVariablesForBuild.bat which generate TempEnvVariables.properties
file. This properties file contains update value of year,Week_number, week_day
and now i need to update my build variable as per ***${year}0${Week_number}${week_day}***

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'Build_Machine_Windows_Server' }
    stages {
       stage('Build') {
          steps {
            dir ('E:\\\\Jenkins'){
                 bat 'call E:\\Jenkins\\CalculateTempEnvVariablesForBuild.bat'   

            }  
             load "E:\\Jenkins\\TempEnvVariables.properties" 

             withEnv(['build=${year}0${Week_number}${week_day}']) {
                      echo "${build}"    
                    }

             echo "${year}"
             echo "${week_day}"
             echo "${Week_number}"
          }
       }
    }
}
```

when i do echo ${build}, its no giving me update value instead it gives me plain string -> **${year}0${Week_number}${week_day}** what i need is **20173203**
when i do echo of year, week_day and Week_number individually, i get correct value like **17,32,03**

I guess i am not setting/injecting variable correctly (may be syntax error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipeline code is using single quotes. According to [the docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-withenv-code-set-environment-variables), this means interpolation is NOT done by groovy, but by the underlying shell:

> (Note that here we are using single quotes in Groovy, so the variable
>   expansion is being done by the Bourne shell, not Jenkins.)

Try using double quotes:

```
withEnv(["build=${BUILD_NUMBER}"]) {
    echo env.build
}
```